# Pass base64_encode() to a variable

Tags: php, variables, base64

I want to pass `base64_encode($data)` to a variable. I tried doing that, and when I print_r out, I don't get anything in the output. How can I pass `base64_encode($data)` to a variable?

Here's the code:

```
$data = $imageData;
$hello = base64_encode($data);
print_r($helo);
```

Comment: typo? print_r($helo);

Comment: That answered it. Thanks!